# Changing the iOS keyboard animation time

Tags: ios, animation, keyboard, duration

Is there a way to change the time the iOS keyboard animation takes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've actually found a better solution. What you can do is programmatically make the textfield or textview a first responder within an animation with duration of your choice. Example for making the keyboard emerge over the course of one second might be:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
{
     [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}];
```

Similarly, you can make the keyboard disappear like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
    {
         [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }];
```

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have any shipping code that does this and made it through Apple review?  Seems like they may not like you messing with standard animations.

Comment: Hmm...that's a good point, I hadn't thought of that. I don't have any code in the app store yet, but I'm going to update one of my apps in the coming weeks with this code, so I'll certainly update the post to reflect the results!

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this without also animating the insertion point?

Comment: Is there a way to change the duration when the user actually taps the UITextField instead of programmatically calling [textField becomeFirstResponder]?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem @nonamelive ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Randy I think if you subclass UITextField and override becomeFirstResponder, you can use my above solution but call [super becomeFirstResponder] (and [super resignFirstResponder]) instead.