# Showing a keyboard in iOS without animating

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, animation, keyboard

Does anyone know if there is a way to show the keyboard in iOS without animating it? Or better yet, can you change the animation speed?

Thanks

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542495/changing-the-ios-keyboard-animation-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of, is pushing a view controller which has a view which is made first responder in `-viewDidLoad`. (`viewWillAppear` will probably do fine as well)

Pushing it without animation might get you a keyboard popping up without animation.

**update** too bad, it seems either the view animates into screen (modally or pushed on the navigation stack, with `animated:YES`) with the keyboard fixed, or the view comes up without animation (i.e. `animated:NO`) making the keyboard animate into screen again.

Comment: Be aware that adding it to viewDidLoad can mess with -textFieldShouldReturn delegate method in release builds.