# Getting Animated for UItextview Keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-softkeyboard

ISSUE: The UItextview Keyboard Getting Animated.

Am doing one iphone app. In this app am using the UItextview. So now am putting [textview BecomeFirstResponder] for getting Uitextview keyboard active. But that uitextview keyboard getting animated. Now How can i avoid the animating. Please some body help me to solve this issue.Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542495/changing-the-ios-keyboard-animation-time

Comment: Sorry it is not working. Am very sorry.@R.A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keyboard is not currently in view and you then call `becomeFirstResponder` on a text view (or text field), the keyboard will animate into view. There is no way to make the keyboard appear without any animation.